# Turning sound into a graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks, sound

I'm writing a comprehensive text on graphs and Mathematica and in this context I have this, let's call it, creative gap between sound and graphs. There are plenty of ways one can create graphs from and to objects; [meshes](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/data-and-mesh-regions/), [morphological graphs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MorphologicalGraph.html) from images, to/from [(sparse) matrices](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/GraphsAndMatrices.html), [curated data](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphData.html)...but how to turn sound into a graph?

One could use a [discrete Markov process](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscreteMarkovProcess.html) to transition between [chords](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SoundNote.html), for example, but I don't see a solution in the other direction. Note, I'm not asking thousand lines of code, just a simple textbook-like example or idea.

Comment: Would be great if you could provide a sound, and the expected graph.

Comment: Do you want the graphs that are part of a `Sound` object, e.g. the output of `Import["ExampleData/rule30.wav"]`?

Comment: I don't have an expected graph for a sound. For an arbitrary wav or mp3, how would you represent the data contained in this sound as a graph? It's a conceptual question, not so much a technical one. Though I'd be happy if there was a magical line of code.

Comment: He! Reminded me of this http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/3764/315

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `Sound` objects like

```
sound = Import["ExampleData/rule30.wav"]
```

> [image: Sound]

*Mathematica* creates a visual representation be default.
To use it in your own visualizations, you can extract this information by

```
ListLinePlot[sound[[1, 1]], PlotRange -> All]
```

> [image: Sound1]

and do something like

```
Graph@Table[
 sound[[1, 1, 1]][[n]] <-> sound[[1, 1, 1]][[n + 1]], 
 {n, 1, Length@sound[[1, 1, 1]] - 1}]
```

> [image: Sound3]

```
Graph@Table[
 sound[[1, 1, 1]][[n]] <-> sound[[1, 1, 1]][[n + 1]], {n, 1, 100}]
```

> [image: moreSound]

Comment: `Graph[] =!= Plot[]` :D

Comment: @belisarius I thought he meant [graph](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/graph) and not [`Graph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graph.html?q=Graph) ;-).

Comment: I've always wondered how to solve the traveling salesman problem without being able to see...

Comment: Yes, the fact that people use 'graph' for barcharts and whatnot is annoying. Same for 'network' and 'diagram', in fact. In any case, brilliant solution @Karsten-7. Lovely floral graphs :)

Comment: @FrancoisVanderseypen Thanks! And and also thank you to belisarius for his hint.

Comment: I don't understand -- is this somehow a meaningful graph? What does adjacency represent here?

Comment: @KellenMyers The meaningfulness is up to you and your interpretation. For an easier understanding of what is represented in the last `Graph`, just compare it to `ListPlot[sound[[1, 1, 1]][[;; 100]], PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: I know what the command does. What I don't understand is how this graph has any meaningful interpretation -- if it doesn't, just say so. That's not up to me. If someone said "how do I turn a sound wave into an image" and someone said "take a screenshot of the icon for the sound file" I would question that too.